# Histogram without arrays

Tags: java, histogram

I have to write which reads from the user three non-negative integers and then
prints, using symbols '*', a `histogram' of the data represented by the numbers, i.e.,
three vertical bars, aligned at the bottom, with heights equal to the values of the
three numbers.
For example, for numbers 3, 1 and 8 the result should look like this:

```
*
*
*
*
*
* *
* *
***
```

Actually I wrote the following  program but it prints  a pyramid of asterisks with the base of the number entered:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Task1 {
public static void main (String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter a positive odd number: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
     scan.close();

     for (int len=1, sp=n/2; len <= n; len+=2, --sp) {
         for (int i = 0; i < sp; ++i)
             System.out.print(" ");
         for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
         }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Start by reading the three numbers !   Then have an attempt that uses all of them.  (You’ll want to count down from the maximum of them)

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in three numbers");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    int c = scan.nextInt();

       int max = 0;

    if (a>b && a>c){
        max = a;
    } else if (b>a && b>c){
        max = b;
    } else if (c>a && c>b){
        max = c;
    }

        for (int i = 8; i>=1; --i) {
            if (i>a) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            if (i>b){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }else {
                  System.out.print("*");
             }
            if (i>c){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

}